# Font setting for Office365 doesn't save

Tags: web-applications, outlook, font-size, office365

I've got a weird font problem in Outlook web application.

The default font for writing e-mails refuses to change to size 10, if I configure it to size 8, it'll be size 8. If I set it to size 12, it'll be size 12. If I set it to size 10, it will stay whatever I last put it at.

The issue seems to be on the server. The same problem exists, no matter what computer or browser I log on with.

Does anyone else have this kind of weird behavior?

Are there any controls on the 'server side' that could solve this, or could my profile be reset somehow (without loosing any emails).

Thank you in advance for any and all suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This seem weird. Call support, it's free and they are probably the right people to help you.

Comment: I read here http://onlinehelp.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-enterprises/ff637572.aspx that I have to sign in as an Admin to get the phone number, but I am not an admin.  


The issue is quit an annoyance, but our admin is so overburdened that I don't want to bother him with a non-critical issue...


I found by the way that Firefox is OK (now?), but Chrome and IE 9.0 still have this issue....